# Needs to verify developer often

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, code-signing

*Let me start by saying that this is not a programming question.*

I have developed an `iOS` app that will be used internally in our company for prototyping/testing. It is available on only one iPhone 7. I am using xcode to program the iPhone and I have a paid apple developer account which should be valid for 10 more months or so.

My problem is that every now and then (maybe after 4-5 days) when the app starts, it just disappears directly(kind of looks like it crashes instantly). The window does not really pop up, it just disappears.

The only way I have found to resolve this issue is to connect it to my `Mac`, then program the iPhone again via `xcode` at which point it ask me to verify the developer (`via General > Device Settings > Verify...`) then the app starts working again for a couple of days again.

Why is this happening? This is really annoying if I am not close to my computer.
I get it that it needs to be verified once but this is just crazy.
What am I missing here?

Comment: if its provisioning profile used is one from a free developer account, i think the apps provisioning profile expires within a week, if you are on a paid account, i think its a year.

Comment: @Fonix please see update, I have a paid developer account

Comment: are you using the default xcode generated provisioning profile? maybe login to your developer account and create your own provisioning profile and specifically use that one, if you arent already